Create relationship between rows in different tables
I have two tables in SQL Server where there is a discrepancy between some of the values for grouping purposes.
The tables look like this:
A   B   C     D    E
JA HOB Sell Nov24  17.00
JA HOB Buy  Nov24  18.00
JA HOB Sell Dec24  10.00
JA HOB Buy  Dec24  11.00
MQ HOB Sell Nov24  12.00
MQ HOB Buy  Nov24  13.00
MQ HOB Sell Dec24  12.00
MQ HOB Buy  Dec24  13.00
BA HOB Sell Sep24  26.00
BA HOB Buy  Sep24  27.00
BA HOB Sell Nov24  28.00
BA HOB Buy  Nov24  29.00

A   B   C     D    E
JA HOB Sell Jul24  10.10
JA HOB Buy  Jul24  11.20
MQ HOB Sell Nov24  15.30
MQ HOB Buy  Nov24  16.40
MQ HOB Sell Dec24  12.30
MQ HOB Buy  Dec24  13.40
BA HOB Sell Sep24  26.10
BA HOB Buy  Sep24  27.20
BA HOB Sell Dec24  28.10
BA HOB Buy  Dec24  29.20

I need to create the following output:
A   B   C     D    E      E2
JA HOB Sell Nov24  17.00  10.10
JA HOB Buy  Nov24  18.00  11.20
JA HOB Sell Dec24  10.00  10.10
JA HOB Buy  Dec24  11.00  11.20
MQ HOB Sell Nov24  12.00  15.30
MQ HOB Buy  Nov24  13.00  16.40
MQ HOB Sell Dec24  12.00  12.30
MQ HOB Buy  Dec24  13.00  13.40
BA HOB Sell Sep24  26.00  26.10
BA HOB Buy  Sep24  27.00  27.20
BA HOB Sell Nov24  28.00  28.10
BA HOB Buy  Nov24  29.00  29.20

I need to group by columns A-D, but as you can see from the tables the dates do not match (which I have no control over). For the most part the dates will match, but there are some instances where this is not the case and I am not sure how to account for it. Excluding the date in the group would not be an option because there will be multiple duplicates of values for columns A-C.
Is there a relationship I can create between the two tables to ensure that I can join the right values and create the expected output? or is there a better way to go about it?
EDIT: I need to map column E in table 2 to a whole row in table 1 based on 4 things: ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, and ColumnD. In table 2, for the most part all 4 columns will be 1:1 with table 1 meaning there will be a record in table 2 that matches all 4 of the above columns in table 1. However, some of the records in table 2 will not be 1:1, and the date will not match correctly. Even more so, for JA there will always only be 2 records in table 2, where now it needs to be mapped based solely on Columns A,B and C.

How did you decide to eliminate the Jul24 records?

Essentially the records in the second table are useless. I am only concerned with column E and how it relates to the first table. That value needs to be mapped to a row in the first table (which would be the Dec24 record not Jul24). I can edit it in the example, but there will be multiple duplicate values if I were to just remove the date(e.g. JA, HOB, Sell). And since the dates do not align, I am unsure how to relate column E in table 2 to the correct rows in table 1 @Randy

Before anyone can assist with an SQL solution, you need to clearly explain the mapping logic you desire in words. The only logic I can think of for what you show is, map every row to the same row number, and if you run out of rows start again from 0. But I can't imagine that is your actual logic.

@DaleK okay I can edit the question and clarify

@DaleK updated. if you need more clarification let me know.

That doesn't explain anything at all about how you want the columns that don't match mapped. What logic should be used, specifically in those cases where there isn't a match, to choose the matching row? (ideally you need more example of non-matching rows also).

@DaleK that is kind of what the question is asking about how becuase I am not sure honestly.  If a record in table 2 does not match a record in table 1 based on columns A,B,C,D then I am unsure how to proceed since I need a different way to relate the rows. Except for the case of JA where you can just map it based on A,B,C instead.  I can update the example now

As I said above we can only help build a SQL solution... you have to decide what logic you want, you (and I guess your colleagues) are the only people who know your system details and therefore when you look at this bust data, you can somehow work out what will be acceptable to you as a company. But we can't help you with that decision.

Perhaps you can come up with a rule by which to get the desired result from the source tables. And even several options. However, only you can tell what the meaning of this table connection is and (maybe) the meaning of these values. Sell and Buy are talking about some kind of movement and balance. Some kind of fifo/lifo;) (https://dbfiddle.uk/tw2TLOuL)
